# SAL annotations, which one to use?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, annotations

So I have dipped my toes into source code annotations for C++, but discovered there are many ways to Rome, so to speak.

Examples:

```
__in

_In_

[Pre(FormatString(Style="printf")] LPCSTR format
```

- [VS2005 SAL Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [VS2010 Using Annotations to Reduce C/C++ Code Defects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032%28v=vs.100%29)
- [VS2012 Using SAL Annotations to Reduce C/C++ Code Defects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032%28v=vs.110%29)

Is there **one**-microsoft-way to do this?

Comment: SAL could only potentially make sense for C, not for C++. But consider that Microsoft got even the annotations of `MessageBox` wrong. This means that SAL is worse than worthless junk: it adds extreme verbosity which slows programmers down, and the little information it conveys is often wrong (as my example illustrates), thus not only slowing programmers down but actively misleading them. So even for C I'd say it's pretty *counter-productive* to use SAL. **Just say NO!**

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I can't speak for userland code, but SAL is actually pretty beneficial for drivers.  Particularly the `_IRQL` annotations

Comment: @brc: uhm, I looked at it. apart from the question "would SAL be the only way to achieve guarantees" it looks horribly complex, while interrupt request levels in themselves are a simple thing. so it reminds me strongly of Microsoft's "apartment" added-complexity scheme for threading in COM. many people thought that was meaningful. many people still think e.g. `WinMain` (just added, counter-productive meaningless complexity) is a good idea. so, i strongly suspect that's the case also for SAL _IRCL annotations: that they're just needlessly added complexity and obfuscation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft has introduced a new SAL standard ([SAL 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx)) starting with Windows 8<sup>1</sup>.  SAL 2.0 uses the single underscore style of annotations, such as `_In_opt_` [among others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382).  Thus, for all new code, the best practice would be to follow the SAL 2.0 style, as [slides](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15122-f10/lectures/25-sal.pdf) from Microsoft exhibit.

For older code, the general rule of "stay consistent" seems to be the best way to go, but if you feel inclined to update all your annotations, again follow the SAL 2.0 style.

--

<sup>1</sup> - SAL 2.0 has actually been around since 2010 (check the date on the linked presentation), but it hasn't been officially supported externally until Windows 8, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: VS2010 uses both SAL flavours.  The older declspec SAL for the Windows API and the newer attribute SAL for the CRT.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, since SAL annotations is a meta-language that can help static analysis tools  to check the for bug at compile time, I think it might be compiler dependent ( for complex checks at least to some extent )
So you might not have one-way for all of them, but the transition from one to the other is not too complicated